# Google翻訳の結果を回答に使って良いですか？

Tags: サポート

ときどき、Google 翻訳の結果を回答に使っている例を見ます。

しかし、スタック・オーバーフローに投稿されたコンテンツは Creative Commons でライセンスされます。Google 翻訳の結果を掲載するのはライセンス的に大丈夫なのでしょうか？　Google 翻訳を使っていることまで明記すれば引用の範囲ですか？

Answer (score 2):

注意: 私は法律の専門家ではありませんので、本当に必要であるならば、専門家に相談するべきです。

その、 Google 翻訳の元のコンテンツが CC-by-SA compatible な形で翻訳者に提供されている、その場合のみにおいて、 Google 翻訳は特に制限なく投稿可能なはずです。

そうでない限り、 翻訳の投稿者は、著作権における引用の要件を満たす必要があると思っています。どうやったら引用として適切なのかは、私には判断できないので、この場では詳細は述べないでおきます。

Comment: 部分的に反対で、元のコンテンツが Creative Commons であったとしても Google 翻訳の結果を Creative Commons 扱いにはできないのではないかと疑っています。たとえば過去に Ubuntu の翻訳に Google 翻訳の結果が混入してしまったので revert したという事例があり、この際には駄目だという話になっています（私も法律の専門家ではないので厳密なところは分かりかねますが……）: https://togetter.com/li/1084225

Comment: FWIW として、 ^ の nekketsuuu さんのリンクを元に、探していった結果、次のまとめページを発掘したので、ここに共有しておきます: https://anond.hatelabo.jp/20170225195916